# Failing testSetup within Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

From time to time the test setup fails at our automation which is run by Jenkins. When the test setup fails, it will skip all other test setups and tests in the suit. It is run on Mozilla Firefox.

Is there any chance to get rid of the exception?

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
1469480338859   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1469480338873   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1469480338875   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1469480338879   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1469480338880   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1469480338881   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1469480338882   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1469480338883   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7098252712982546494webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1469480338883   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping JSErrorCollector@jsourcerer.com to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7098252712982546494webdriver-profile\extensions\JSErrorCollector@jsourcerer.com
1469480338884   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7098252712982546494webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1469480338884   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1469480338894   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Directory state JSON differs: cache [] state [{"name":"app-global","addons":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","mtime":1434617609039,"rdfTime":1417010916000}}},{"name":"app-profile","addons":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous7098252712982546494webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","mtime":1469480305220,"rdfTime":1469480305217},"JSErrorCollector@jsourcerer.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous7098252712982546494webdriver-profile\\extensions\\JSErrorCollector@jsourcerer.com","mtime":1469480303712,"rdfTime":1469480303712}}}]
1469480338900   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7098252712982546494webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1469480338901   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1469480339870   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1469480339874   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1469480339878   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1469480339878   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on JSErrorCollector@jsourcerer.com installed in app-profile
1469480339886   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:JSErrorCollector@jsourcerer.com visible
1469480339887   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1469480339887   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1469480339887   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1469480339892   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1469480339893   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1469480339893   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1469480339907   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1469480339907   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1469480339908   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1469480339919   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1469480339921   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1469480339924   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1469480339925   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1469480349163   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1469480349708   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:124)
    at com.intuit.ifs.csscat.core.WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:104)
    at com.intuit.ifs.csscat.core.BaseTestNGWebDriver.testSetup(BaseTestNGWebDriver.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:551)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:640)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:894)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1219)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:768)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1188)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1113)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1025)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:70)

Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe)
```

Comment: As per the error the firefox connection is not being made between firefox and selenium. Can you make sure of the version and the ram availability is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when it can't start up the requested web driver. There are two instances that I've personally see this happen: (1) when there are incompatibilities between the Selenium version and the Firefox version and (2) when there are too many instances of Firefox running already and the binary fails to launch. Since you said this is intermittent, I'm assuming (1) isn't the issue and would assume that you are running into (2). I don't know if you are running your tests in parallel or not and with not knowing the setup of your automation I'd say the simple solution would be to wrap the creation of the WebDriver in a loop with a try-catch block to handle that exception. I'd recommend **not** making the loop infinite (e.g. give it a timeout). Note also that this is the simple solution, but not necessarily the best. Usually how best to handle resource management is highly dependent on the test environment, the number of tests you run, the parallelism (if any), etc.

Also, note that with TestNG if you have exceptions in configuration methods (e.g. setup) it will skip other tests as it takes a "fail fast on bad configurations" mentality to running tests. If you **don't** want that you need to be consistent in catching and handling all exceptions inside those configuration methods.

Comment: Thanks for great answer Aaron. We are running test in parallel. Different suits but on the same server so this must be the case. I will discuss it internally what solution might be the best and talk to you back if it helped and how we solved it.